# Why is not my memory running on dual channel?

Tags: memory, ddr3

I have just upgraded my computer from 8GB DDR3 1600 to 16GB. I bought the same brand and specs, Kingston Hyper X 1600 DDR3. My motherboard is and [Asus B85M-G](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1150/B85M-G/E9884_B85M-G_Manual_v4_print_vendor_only.pdf), I connected them to B1 and B2 slots which should be Channel B.

This is CPU-Z output:

[image: Memory Module 01]
[image: Memory Module 02]
[image: CPU-Z showing single channel]

What can I do?

Comment: Nice that you included a link to the manual but if you do consider linking the English one. Did you try other memory configurations?

Comment: You say "I bought the same brand and specs", but your screenshots show different specs for the different memory modules!

Comment: *"I connected them to B1 and B2 slots which should be Channel B"* -- For dual channel, the memory modules have to use two (2) channels, e.g. one module in channel A socket and another module in channel B socket.  You are only using the sockets of just one (1) channel.

Comment: Thanks Seth for your edit and your help,  sawdust was right. I swapped to a1+b1 and now shows dual channel: https://ibb.co/wdxG64k . Just one question if you allow me, if I set A1+B1 and A2+B2, how many channels will it have? one of 32gb or 2 of 16gb,  just curious about it.